# php calculate discount or tax

Tags: php, math, bcmath

I'm trying to calculate a tax or discount value using BCMATH in PHP. I need 2 DECIMAL PLACES. Here's how i'm doing it:

```
bcscale(2);
$price = '60.67';
$discount = bcmul(bcdiv($price, 100), '3.8'); // calculate 3.8 percent from 60.67
// result is: 2.28
// result should be: 2.31
```

I could simply increase the scale to 4 or something like that and that would now give me a correct result.

So the question is: how should i do this correctly? Should i set the scale to 4 and then sprintf('%0.2f', $discount) in the end? Or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Bypass bcmath?

```
$discount = round( ($price / 100) * 3.8, 2);
// 2.31
```

Comment: Otherwise, try removing the quotes around 3.8 and put scale as third param:

Comment: $discount = bcmul(bcdiv($price, 100), 3.8, 2);

Comment: So you're saying i can bypass bcmath alltogether. Then ... what is the point of using it anyway and what are the situations in which i can bypass it?

Comment: Just saying if it's giving you incorrect results and your syntax is correct, just use regular PHP functions. You can use them inside your other code

Comment: It would give correct results, using correct scale. And it's obvious why it doesn't in the first place. Just wondering if using a simple float math would not end up screwing something up even if it's a single operation ...

Comment: Shouldn't do, at the end of the day bc takes and returns integers so it shouldn't matter. For consistency you should stick with one or the other if you can though

Comment: I believe I found the problem. BCMath doesn't round to the decimal place. Instead it simply cuts off at the decimal. Example: 2.325 in bcmath would be 2.32 not 2.33